# How do i join same table and sort it in sql?

Tags: sql, join

I have table  like below one -

```
Name      Null     Type         
--------- -------- ------------ 
ID        NOT NULL NUMBER       
Name               VARCHAR2(20) 
PARENT_ID          NUMBER
```

Table contents

```
ID        Name     PARENT_ID
--------- -------- ------------ 
1         Ramesh    null*
2         Ajay      1
```

I want to find out best SQL join query where I can populate the results like below.

For each row I want to know the ParentName not ID. How can I do that ?

```
ID        Name     ParentName
--------- -------- ------------ 
1         Ramesh    null*
2         Ajay      Ramesh
```

*null or blank

This is not example of the my requirement.

I have tried below SQL with left join but I am not sure if its the proper way.

```
SELECT S1.ID,S1.CRID AS PARENT_CRID,S2.CRID AS CRID  FROM DAJ_JOINS S1
left JOIN DAJ_JOINS S2
ON S1.ID=S2.PARENT_ID
order by id  asc;
```

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla, how can you tell? It has both MySQL and SQL Server tags...

Comment: Do you need to find just one parent or all parents?

Comment: Didn't your query return what you want? Looks like the proper way to me.

Comment: Hmm, probably MySQL, since afaik SQL Server doesn't have varchar2.

Comment: It is proper query, just in a select he forgot to add the "Name" column

Comment: How can it be 'blank' ?!?!?!

Comment: sorry edited the tags

Answer (score 1):

Your query is close but the joining clause needs to be reversed as

```
select 
t1.ID,
t1.Name,
t2.Name as PARENT_Name
from DAJ_JOINS t1
left join DAJ_JOINS t2 on t1.PARENT_ID = t2.ID
order by t1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server 2005+, you can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM DAJ_JOINS D
  OUTER APPLY (SELECT Name As Parent_Name FROM DAJ_JOINS WHERE ID = D.Parent_ID) A
```